# Create a contact map from two Dataframe in r

Tags: r, matrix

I have two data similar as follows:

```
df1 <-structure(
list(
  sample_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
  motif = c("CT-G.A", "TA-C.C", "TC-G.C", "TC-G.C", "CG-A.T", "CA-G.T"),
  chromosome = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2"),
  position = c(7300L, 1000L, 1200L, 3000L, 12000L, 2000L)
),
.Names = c("sample_id", "motif", "chromosome", "position"),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,-6L))
df2 <-structure(
list(
  geneID = c("E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5"),
  chromosome = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2"),
  start = c(100L, 1100L, 1200L,400L, 12000L),
  end = c(10300L, 20100L, 2000L, 20000L, 20000L)
),
.Names = c("geneID", "chromosome", "start", "end"),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,-5L))
```

Each row of the df1 is related to a mutation, the first column of the df1 is patient's name. The second column of the df1 is the motif of that mutation, the third column shows its chromosome and the fourth column represent the location where the mutation occurred.
The first column of the df2 represents the name of the gene. The second column represents the chromosome. The third and fourth columns represent the beginning and the end of a gene.

So I want to create a matrix from these data which each entry shows the number of patients that have the same motif at the same gene as like as follow:

```
          E1_CT-G.A    E1_TA-C.C      ... E5_CA-G.T
E1_CT-G.A     1            1                   0   
E1_TA-C.C     1            1                   0     
.             .            .                   .   
.             .            .                   .      
.             .            .                   .      
E5_CA-G.T     0            0         ...       0
```

i.e. entry (i,j) of matrix shows the number of patients that have a mutation in 
 both gene_motif i and gene_motif j.

Comment: Perhaps `crossprod(table(df1[1:2]))`

Comment: I need df2 for finding gene name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 %>%
  fuzzy_join(df2, by = c("position" = "start", "position" = "end", "chromosome" = "chromosome"), 
             match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`, `==`)) %>%
  mutate(gene_motif = paste(geneID, motif, sep = "_")) %>%
  group_by(sample_id, gene_motif) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(gene_motif)) %>%
  select(sample_id, gene_motif) %>%
  table %>%
  crossprod 

           gene_motif
gene_motif  E1_CT-G.A E1_TA-C.C E2_CT-G.A E3_CA-G.T E3_TC-G.C E4_CA-G.T E4_CG-A.T E4_TC-G.C E5_CG-A.T
  E1_CT-G.A         1         1         1         0         1         0         0         1         0
  E1_TA-C.C         1         1         1         0         1         0         0         1         0
  E2_CT-G.A         1         1         1         0         1         0         0         1         0
  E3_CA-G.T         0         0         0         1         0         1         1         0         1
  E3_TC-G.C         1         1         1         0         1         0         0         1         0
  E4_CA-G.T         0         0         0         1         0         1         1         0         1
  E4_CG-A.T         0         0         0         1         0         1         1         0         1
  E4_TC-G.C         1         1         1         0         1         0         0         1         0
  E5_CG-A.T         0         0         0         1         0         1         1         0         1
```

So first perform a fuzzy join based on position and chromosome, then make an additional column which is a combination of `geneID` and `motif`, filter duplicates, since you are not interested in the number of co-occurring  mutations but rather sample id's and then do a co-occurrence calculation.